# Get User email wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

this question is a little strange, but I know that surely some of you will know how to answer.

I have an activecampaign form, and I would like to auto-populate the email field. The form is implemented by an embed I found a guide but tells me to use integration via url. Now I ask you, is it possible to take the user's email and populate the email field?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can we see your best practices?

Comment: input type="text" name="email" placeholder="" value="pippo" required/

Comment: can you please add your code in question  so other can easily understand and guide you in better way.

Comment: get your current user id and fetch the record it's very easy for more detail please visit [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/)

Comment: @Dhruv the code it's too long i have shared the code here https://codeshare.io/5oV6Wb

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about getting the current logged in user email this is what you need to do

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_email   = $current_user->user_email;
}
```

First you check if the current user is logged in to the site, then you retrieve the users data. You don't have to get the users email and store it in a variable but it helps with keeping your code clean.

Now you need to populate the form. Lets say that this is the form field.

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?= ( !empty( $user_email ) ) ? $user_email : ''; ?>" placeholder="" required/>
```

What we did here is check if the variable that hold the user email is not empty, if it's not empty then set the value to the user email, if it's empty then output an empty string, which is equivalent to an empty value.

Hope this help =]

Comment: have you see my code? Where i must put the code ( if ) ?

Comment: I would suggest putting the code at the top of the page, don't forget to wrap the code in a valid php tag "<?php if () ..... ?>", i would also suggest commenting this code for your future self, it will help you understand what you did and generally commenting your code will help you in the long term =].